# how to store different get variable in an array

Tags: php

There's a `$_GET` variable and it sends a value each time user clicks an element. On the first click `someData_1` is sent, on the second click `someData_2` is sent and so on.

I want to create an array and put the data in one after another into the array:

```
if (isset[$_GET['myGetVar'])) {
    $myVar = $_GET['myGetVar']; // right now it holds data_1
}
```

How can I grab that `data_1` and put it in :

```
$myArray[0];
```

and user clicks again so:

```
if (isset[$_GET['myGetVar'])) {
    $myVar = $_GET['myGetVar']]; // right now it holds data_2
}
```

How can i grab this `data_2` in put it in:

```
$myArray[1]
```

and the next data in `$myArray[2]` and `$myArray[3]`.

I don't want to INSERT this data into a database. (If that's possible)

Comment: Take a look at some other questions here and how they're formatted.

Comment: You could use $_SESSION or $GLOBALS to achieve what you want, but until you give us properly formatted question, you wont get more specific answer.

Comment: you need to attach all variables one after another with each click into array: `...php?id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=3`..

Comment: new to site can't find the damn tool where is it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_GET['foo'])) {
    $_SESSION['foos'][] = $_GET['foo'];
    var_dump($_SESSION['foos']);
}
```

Comment: Wut? No idea what you're asking.

Comment: the code you sent how did you style it? white space background color

Comment: Oh my god It's a pain in the ass to style the code before you post it here I give up, I've got myself a headache!

Comment: Seriously? Highlighting your text and clicking `{}` in the toolbar gives you a headache?

Comment: OMG I was trying to bold it and indent it manually, NOW WE'RE COOKIN!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

session_start();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
  $_SESSION['arr'][] = $_POST['myGetVar'];

echo "
  <form method='POST' action='.'>
    <input type='text' name='myGetVar'/>
    <input type='submit'/>
  </form>";

if (isset($_SESSION['arr']))
  echo '<xmp>'.print_r($_SESSION['arr'], true).'</xmp>';

?>
```